# determing cell x and y of a canvas grid

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a nodejs application that creates a grid within a canvas currently using for loops. I need help writing an algorithm to determine which cell i my cursor is currently in x and y wise. The grid is currently 25x25 and I am tracking mouse movements within the canvas. Instead of giving me a raw x and y mouse coordinate I would like a cell coordinates. any help? thanks!

```js
//START {EXPRESS}
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);
 
app.get('/',function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
 
serv.listen(2000);
console.log("Server started.");


var io = require('socket.io')(serv,{});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
 //RETRIEVING THE MOUSE X AND Y COORDINATES
 socket.on('mouseMove', function(data){
  console.log(data.x + ", " + data.y);
 });

});
```

```html
<div id="gameDiv">
 <center>
 <canvas id="ctx" width="750" height="750" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
 </center>
</div>
 
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
 
<script>
 //NETWORK VARIABLES
 var socket = io();
 //GETTING THE CANVAS BY ID
 var canvas = document.getElementById("ctx");
 context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 
 //GRID VARIABLES
 var w=30,
 h=30,
 row=25,
 col=25,
 x=0,
 y=0;
 
 //LOOP TO DRAW THE GRID
 for(x=0; x<row; x++){
  for(y=0; y<col; y++){
   context.strokeRect(w*x,h*y,w,h);
  }
 }
 
 //GETTING THE MOUSE X AND Y
 function getMousePos(canvas, event){
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
   x:event.clientX - rect.left,
   y:event.clientY - rect.top
  };
 }
 
 canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
  var pos = getMousePos(canvas, event);
  var posx = pos.x;
  var posy = pos.y;
  
        socket.emit('mouseMove',{x:x, y:y});
 }, false);
 
 
 
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Divide x/y coordinates by cell width/height and then round down to get cell coordinates

Answer (score 0):

AH I ended up figuring it out myself.

the algorithm is posx / height rounded up
posy / width rounded up

here is the html

```html
<div id="gameDiv">
 <center>
 <canvas id="ctx" width="750" height="750" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
 </center>
</div>
 
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
 
<script>
 //NETWORK VARIABLES
 var socket = io();
 //GETTING THE CANVAS BY ID
 var canvas = document.getElementById("ctx");
 context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 
 //GRID VARIABLES
 var w=30,
 h=30,
 row=25,
 col=25,
 x=0,
 y=0,
 cX=0,
 cY=0;
 
 //LOOP TO DRAW THE GRID
 for(x=0; x<row; x++){
  for(y=0; y<col; y++){
   context.strokeRect(w*x,h*y,w,h);
  }
 }
 
 //GETTING THE MOUSE X AND Y
 function getMousePos(canvas, event){
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
   x:event.clientX - rect.left,
   y:event.clientY - rect.top
  };
 }
 
 canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event){
  
  var pos = getMousePos(canvas, event);
  var posx = pos.x;
  var posy = pos.y;
  
  **cX = Math.ceil(posx/30);
  cY = Math.ceil(posy/30);**
  
        socket.emit('mouseMove',{x:cX, y:cY});
 }, false);
```